# append: true for SourceMapDevToolPlugin make an error

Tags: webpack

Using webpack2,with this configuration:

```
{
plugins: [
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            columns: true,
            append: true,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        })
    ]
}
```

Then an error will be thrown when building:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDVJd.png)

if I set **append** to false,the error will disappear.Is it relay to the mode name of devtool,which mode should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The `append` option takes a string, that is appended to the assets. And because you can use `[url]`, which will be replaced with the URL of the source map, it calls [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). But you're giving it a boolean, which doesn't have such a method.

`false` is just a special case, to prevent it from appending anything. So the type of `append` is:

```
append: false | string
```